# How to host Angular application with Kestrel

Tags: asp.net-core, ng-build, fileprovider-extension

I am trying to deploy an `Angular 7` application with  `.NET Core` using `Kestrel` using the `FileProvider` extension.

I have created the angular app , i have `ng build` it and i copied the files inside `dist`  `.NET` Porject.

**Startup**

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
        string jsFolderName = "myroot";
        string prodRoot =Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,jsFolderName);
        string debugRoot =Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),jsFolderName);

        var isDev=env.IsDevelopment();


        DefaultFilesOptions options = new DefaultFilesOptions();
        options.DefaultFileNames.Clear();
        options.DefaultFileNames.Add("/myroot/index.html");
        app.UseDefaultFiles(options);
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions() {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(isDev?debugRoot:prodRoot),
            RequestPath = "/app"
        });
        if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        } else {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

**P.S** My `myroot` folder is right in the root of the project.
I do not know how to feed the first page (entrypoint) of the `angular` app which is `index.html`.

Comment: why dont you use ready templates? I suggest you to look [Mark Pieszak's AspNetCore Angular Universal Template](https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular-universal) or you can use microsoft's Angular template which is already available in VS2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @[Simonare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1118978/simonare) in the comment, the best way is to use official Angular template.

But if you want to serve the static files only, you could do as below :

1. Configure the `DefaultFilesOptions` with `FileProvider` and `RequestPath`.

```
 
    var fileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(isDev?debugRoot:prodRoot);

    DefaultFilesOptions options = new DefaultFilesOptions(){
        RequestPath = "/app",           // to process request to `/app`
        FileProvider = fileProvider,    // to check files under `myroot/**/**`
        DefaultFileNames = new List { "index.html" },
    };
    options.DefaultFileNames.Clear();
    options.DefaultFileNames.Add("/myroot/index.html");
    app.UseDefaultFiles(options);

    // serve static files 
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions() {
        RequestPath = "/app",
        FileProvider = fileProvider,
    });
```

2. Because the path of app is  `https://yourhost:port/app`, you also **need to change the base path within the `index.html`**, so that browser will load all assets (e.g. js, css, img files) relative to current path. The original base of `/src/index.html` is `/`:

   ```html
   <!doctype html>
   <html lang="en">
       <head>
           <meta charset="utf-8">
           <title>App</title>
           <base href="/">
           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
           <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
       </head>
       <body>
           <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
       </body>
   </html>
   ```

Note we need :

- change the `<base href="/">` to `<base href="/app">`
- or change the base to an empty string : `<base href="">`
- or remove that line