# What configuration is necessary to serve Angular files from ASP.NET Core web api project when both projects were generated separately?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

As stated in the title I have two projects which were generated independent of each other. 
1. ASP.NET Core project, was generating using the `dotnet new webapi -o TestAPI`
2. Angular project, generated using the Angular CLI `ng new TestAngularApp`

Since the web api project is the back-end for the angular project, I want it to serve my angular app. Based on my research the way ASP.NET Core serves static files is you have to create a `wwwroot` folder at the root directory of your web api project, and put all of contents produced by the `ng build --prod` command inside that `wwwroot` folder.

The next step is where I am un-sure what I must configure next. Thus far in my `Startup.cs` file in the `Configure` method I have added

`app.UseDefaultFiles();
 app.UseStaticFiles();`

Now this works as expected when I run the webapi project in debug mode straight from Visual Studio. The problem arises when I want to publish the webapi and locally deploy it to IIS.

I run `dotnet publish -c Release` command and all of the files get generated in the `.../publish` directory including the `wwwroot` directory as expected.

In IIS, I then create an application under the `Default Web Site` and point it the `.../publish` directory.

[image: IIS Aplication]

At this point I have enabled `Failed Request Tracing` on the Site level.

When I browse the application, my webapi correctly attempts to serve up the `index.html` file, but it fails to load any of the required assets.

I have tried adding re-write url rules to both the `ThePLeague` application AND the 'wwwroot' directory that is located inside of that application but this does not work. I have tested to make sure my url re-write module does in fact work and it does.

My question is, **Does my webapi require any additional configuration to successfully serve up Angular files?**

Do I need to use the `SpaFallbackException`, `UseSpa`, `UseSpaStaticFiles` or any of the `Spa` prefix extension methods to get this to work, or should the two methods I already have be enough?

Thank you for any insight you can provide.

**UPDATE**

After adjusting the base URL as mentioned in the answer, my files were successfully served. My base url was adjusted to `<base href="/ThePLeague/">`. The problem now however is that when I refresh the page. I receive a 404 error. I have the URL re-write rules sitting in the same directory as the ASP.NET Core webapi and NOT inside the `wwwroot` folder where all of my static files are. This is because when I enable `Failed Request Tracing Rules` in `IIS`, there are no logs generated when having the rules created inside the `wwwroot` folder.

URL re-write rules:

[image]

```
`<system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="test">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot/index.html" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>`
```

Trace logs when I refresh the page:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The Reason

> When I browse the application, my webapi correctly attempts to serve up the index.html file, but it fails to load any of the required assets

The reason is that the default `index.html` generated by `ng new TestAngularApp` sets the `base` as `/`:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TestAngularApp</title>
  <base href="/">
  ....
</head>
```

This will make all your assets path relative to `/`. In other words, the compiled scripts referenced in your `dist/index.html` is relative to the root path `/`:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.06daa30a2963fa413676.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.d64817aaf614d4221ef9.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.b4ca252475698e802446.js"></script>
```

Since you're hosting your angular with the `Virtual Path` of `/ThePLeague`, your assets **URL** should be **prefixed** with `/ThePLeague/`:

```
/ThePLeague/runtime.06daa30a2963fa413676.js
/ThePLeague/polyfills.d64817aaf614d4221ef9.js
/ThePLeague/main.b4ca252475698e802446.js
```

### How to fix

1. Change the base href to **`/ThePLeague/`**:

   ```html
   <base href="/ThePLeague/">
   ```

   Note there's a **trailing `/`** in the `base` href.
2. Restart the `ThePLeague` when need. It should work now.

---

> *Does my webapi require any additional configuration to successfully serve up Angular files?*
>
> *Do I need to use the SpaFallbackException, UseSpa, UseSpaStaticFiles or any of the Spa prefix extension methods to get this to work, or should the two methods I already have be enough?*

Actually, if you don't need a SPA fallback, you don't any other codes except the two `app.UseDefaultFiles();app.UseStaticFiles()` methods you've added.

You don't even have to change the IIS url rewrite rule.

Comment: Thanks for replying back! I adjusted my base URL and it served my files! The issue now is that my url rewrite rules are not working when I refresh the page. Upon refreshing the page I get a 404 error. I will update the question with the logs of the URL rewrite perhaps you can help me narrow down the issue.

Comment: @O.MeeKoh If I understand it correctly, I guess what you want to do is catching all other requests to show the `index.html` as a fallback? If that's the case, there's no need to write the rewrite rules by your own. Simply adding a  `app.UseSpa(spa =>{});` after your `app.UseMvc(...);` will make it.

Comment: so this actually works... Im so lost as to why is there all this fuss about url rewrite rules, when you could just do what you said. Not once have I encountered this in blog posts, or SO posts I've read. Sweet! When would I need angular URL rewrite rules then?

Comment: @O.MeeKoh IMO, there's no need to use URL rewrite in this scenario: IIS URL rewriting is something "global" that happens **before** the ASP.NET Core middlewares.  Although you can do that with IIS rewrite,  the `catch-all` rules might result in something unexpected error when you add more routes in future.  Because your `index.html` should be served as a "fallback" that happens **after** all other routes fail, I think the approach that using middlewares is preferred.

Comment: Makes sense. This makes things so much easier. Now the only issue I am experiencing now is that none of the files inside my `....wwwroot/asset` directory are served correctly.`http://localhost/assets/logo_no_title.png`. You may know off the top of your head. This is all great info going into my OneNote haha

Comment: @O.MeeKoh "none of the files inside my ....wwwroot/asset directory are served correctl": Do you want them served as `http://localhost/logo_no_title.png`? If so, you can register another `UseStaticFiles(opts)` . See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53833968/how-to-host-angular-application-with-kestrel/53844723#53844723